# How to add *all* new/modified files to git, from anywhere? (like `git add -A`, or `git commit -a` for new files)

Tags: git

Is there an equivalent of `git commit -a` for staging new files?

This is the behavior of `git add -A`, but only if you call it from the root directory of your repository. Otherwise, it will only add files in the subdirectory.

Or does there not exist such built-in functionality, making the easiest program to write something like `git add -A $(git rev-parse --show-toplevel)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use git's built-in [aliasses](https://git.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Aliases#Aliases), which include the ability to invoke a shell script.

Comment: Specifically an alias like this, invocable with `git aa` ("aa" for "add all"): `git config --global alias.aa '!sh -c "git add -A $(git rev-parse --show-toplevel)"'`

Comment: @Christopher: Hmm, it seems even simpler. The document claims that *"...(currently, as of git 1.5.6.1) non-git alias are executed from the top-level dir of a repo."* Thus, `git config --global alias.add-a '!git add -A'` is all you need (using ' to avoid shell interpreting !).

Comment: @mschonaker: Thank you, I settled on `git config --global alias.c '!git add -A && git status && read -p "Press any key to type commit message; press ctrl-C to abort" && git commit'`, resulting in an `[alias]` entry of `c = "!git add -A && git status && read -p \"Press any key to type commit message; press ctrl-C to abort\" && git commit"`

Comment: @ninjagecko That's a nice little find of which I was unaware. You might also investigate `git add -p`. It opens an interactive session for `git add` that lets you add chunks of code, as opposed to entire files.

Comment: @ninjagecko you're welcome. That was exactly the shell command I had in mind :P

Comment: For the record, since `git status` is already in the commit message, I am now using `!git add -A && git commit` (though this does not do syntax highlighting depending on your editor). (Also some shells may have trouble with `read -p "..."` in the previous example; one would need `!bash -c "..."` like Christopher originally suggested for that bashism.)